# How to make a PATCH request in ReactJS ? (with Nestjs)

Tags: reactjs, axios, nestjs, patch

nestjs controller.ts

```
   @Patch(':id')
    async updateProduct(
      @Param('id') addrId: string,
      @Body('billingAddr') addrBilling: boolean,
      @Body('shippingAddr') addrShipping: boolean,
    ) {
      await this.addrService.updateProduct(addrId, addrBilling, addrShipping);
      return null;
    }
```

nestjs service.ts

```
 async updateProduct(
    addressId: string,
    addrBilling: boolean,
    addrShipping: boolean,

  ) {
    const updatedProduct = await this.findAddress(addressId);
    if (addrBilling) {
      updatedProduct.billingAddr = addrBilling;
    }
    if (addrShipping) {
      updatedProduct.shippingAddr = addrShipping;
    }
    updatedProduct.save();
  }
```

there is no problem here. I can patch in localhost:8000/address/addressid in postman and change billingAddr to true or false.the backend is working properly.
how can i call react with axios?

page.js

```
    const ChangeBillingAddress = async (param,param2) => {
        try {
            await authService.setBilling(param,param2).then(
                () => {
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
return....
     <Button size='sm' variant={data.billingAddr === true ? ("outline-secondary") : ("info")} onClick={() => ChangeBillingAddress (data._id,data.billingAddr)}>
```

auth.service.js

```
const setBilling = async (param,param2) => {
   let adressid = `${param}`;
   const url = `http://localhost:8001/address/`+ adressid ;
   return axios.patch(url,param, param2).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.token) {
         localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }
      return response.data;
   })
}
```

I have to make sure the parameters are the billlingddress field and change it to true.
I can't make any changes when react button click

Comment: You can install OpenApi in your BackEnd with OpenApi Tools for generate SDK. And this SDK you can use in your FrontEnd !
This allows you to generate an SDK of your API with all the specifics of your endpoints (Param, body, response, etc.)
See : 
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli
- https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation/
- https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction

Comment: this is a bit confusing, it's just get and post in simpler form, I don't understand why I can't get the parameter correctly when patching in react. Thanks anyway, I'll take a look at the your alternative solution. @Jboucly

Comment: Yes I agree but have you checked the CORS of your API before install openapi

Comment: This is potentially a problem with a CORS ? Have you a error message ?

Comment: actually , no error message .I may just not be able to type it correctly, because there is no problem with other methods. As I said, when I write it as a parameter in postman, true or false changes. I can't get it right from react for patch. @Jboucly I'll add a little more detail to the code, you can check it out

Comment: Please do not add solutions as updates to question. Use the answer space below to add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**now it worked correctly**

```
   @Patch('/:id')
    async updateProduct(
      @Param('id') addrId: string,
      @Body('billingAddr') addrBilling: boolean,
    ) {
      await this.addrService.updateProduct(addrId, addrBilling);
      return null;
    }


const ChangeBillingAddress = async (param) => {

    try {
        await authService.setBilling(param,true).then(
            () => {
                window.location.reload();
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


const setBilling= async (param,param2) => {
   let id = `${param}`;
   const url = `http://localhost:8001/address/`+ id;
   return axios.patch(url,{billingAddr: param2}).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.token) {
         localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }
      return response.data;
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since patch method is working fine in postman, and server is also working fine, here's a tip for frontend debugging

Hard code url id and replace param with hard coded values too:

```
const setBilling = async (param,param2) => {
   // let adressid = `${param}`;
   const url = `http://localhost:8001/address/123`; // hard code a addressid 

   return axios.patch(url,param, param2).then((response) => { // hard code params too
      console.log(response); // see console result

      if (response.data.token) {
         // localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }

      // return response.data;
   })
}
```

Comment: I tried it by sending a single parameter, thanks I will update the latest version

Comment: Is it working or not? what's the response object log in the console?

Comment: It is working now, there is an update status above. I couldn't use the parameters correctly, I fixed it.   return axios.patch(url,{billingAddr: param2}).then((response) => { .... 
in this way

Comment: Well, if you find my answer helpful, you can cast an upvote or accept my answer, if you still have some issue left, feel free to reply or create an new question if needed, maybe I will take a look.

Comment: thank you for giving a time. I found it by trying it with my own code. Not your answer, but thanks for your opinion. this part is working as i want

Comment: Yeah, happy coding!